# Symbolic representation for time it takes for a variable to approach a specific value from an initial value

Tags: notation, function-and-relation-composition

For example, I came up with the following problem
"If we have distance $d$ with an initial value of $2 \space feet$, with a secondary value of $10 \space feet$, and it takes us a time $t$ of $64 \space seconds$, what is the acceleration?"

I originally had it written down as this:

$$d = 2 \rightarrow 10$$
$$t = 64$$
$$d_{net} = 8$$
$$\frac{at^2}2 = d_{net}$$
$$\frac{a\cdot 64^2}2 = 8$$
$$\frac{4096a}2 = 8$$
$$2048a = 8$$
$$a = \frac{8}{2048} = \frac{1}{256} = \space .00390625$$

My question is for the $d = 2 \rightarrow 10$ and the $t = 64$ parts, how would one clearly symbolically represent the fact that we are talking about the time it takes $d$ to go from $2$ to $10$?

My guess would be something like:

$$d = 2$$

$$t(d \rightarrow 10) = 64 \space seconds$$

The only thing is that $t$ in this case is not a function, but a value we know. We are saying that the time it takes our distance to increase from $2$ to $10$ **is** $64$ seconds (and we use this in proceeding calculations). Sometimes, though, $t$ may be a function to determine our time, so what would be different in that case?

Comment: I don't think this question is specified clearly enough to be understood.  However, I suspect you are working on distance/velocity/acceleration type problems.  Your question could be reworked to be meaningful as follows:  If we have zero velocity at time 0, and move a distance of 8 meters in 64 seconds using a constant acceleration, what is that acceleration?

Comment: @Michael Basically, but there's a little more nuance to it than that. Let me rewrite my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with problems of constant acceleration $a$, the main equations  are: 
\begin{align}
x(t) &= x(0) + v(0) t + \frac{a}{2}t^2 \quad, \forall t \geq 0 \\
v(t) &= v(0) + at \quad, \forall t \geq 0 \\
a(t) &= a \quad, \forall t \geq 0
\end{align}
where $x(t)$ is position as a function of time; $v(t)$ is velocity as a function of time; $a(t)$ is acceleration as a function of time.  As a consistency check, you can verify that taking time derivatives of the $x(t)$ equation gives you the $v(t)$ equation, and taking time derivatives of the $v(t)$ equation gives you the $a(t)$ equation.

Focusing on the first equation, if we have values for all-but-one of the variables, we can "invert" the equation to solve for the remaining value. In your problem it looks like we have $$t=64, x(0)=2, x(t)=10$$  So
$$ 10 = 2 + v(0)(64) + \frac{a}{2}(64)^2$$
We cannot solve for $a$ unless you specify $v(0)$. In my comment above I explicitly stated that was 0 (to specify a meaningful example problem).

Comment: PS: I found your $d=2\rightarrow 10$ notation a bit confusing since that is not standard notation.

Comment: I know, that's because I was asking about the notation itself. I was going to include a "notation" tag for the question and use "notation" in the question itself, but I couldn't think of the word "notation", so I used "symbolic representation".

So what you're saying is that the notation for establishing that the time is equal to $64 \space seconds$ for $x$ to reach $10$ from an initial value of $2$ is:
$t = 64, \space x(0) = 2, \space x(t) = 10$?

I think I can work with that. I was kinda hoping for something a little more snazzy (and obvious about what we mean), but oh well. Thank you.

Comment: P.S. I understand the bit about the need for specifying $v(0)$, but is it not pretty standard to assume that $v(0) = 0$ if $v(0)$ isn't specified?

Comment: P.P.S. I guess the notation is obvious enough now that I think about it. I just wanted it to be more explicit that we "measured" the time between $x = 2$ and $x = 10$ and found it to be $64 \space seconds$, but I suppose, now that I'm thinking about the equations and the relationships they describe, the notation you specified makes sense.

Comment: The units just need to be consistent.  For example, if distance has units of _meters_ and time has units of _seconds_, then velocity should be _meters/sec_ and acceleration $meters/sec^2$.  Sometimes problems require you to translate the units for consistency, like a value specified in kilometers should be translated to meters. (I always hated problems that did that, as it seemed like an unnecessary distraction.)

Comment: When specifying problems, it is always best to be complete (such as specifying $v(0)=0$). I do not think it is a good idea to make assumptions about unspecified quantities, as it can reinforce incorrect habits. It can also make others wonder if you know whether or not such assumptions are needed.  For example, students often ask questions about random variables $X$ and $Y$ that cannot be solved unless $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but I find the weaker students are typically the ones who "forget" to mention independence, the stronger ones do not forget this important assumption.

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking for something like $$t_1-t_0 :\min_{t_1}\left\{\int_{t_0}^{t_1} f'(t)dt=f_s-f_i\right\} \text{ if } f(t_0) = f_i$$

- $t_0$ initial time
- $t_1$ time for specific value
- $f_i$ initial value at $t_0$
- $f_s$ specific value to reach

It is an integral equation on the time-derivative of the variable/function you are considering.